# Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 shutdown from GUI doesn't work

Tags: gnome, 20.04, shutdown

When I use the right menu from title bar and click shutdown, nothing happens. When I type in terminal

```
sudo shutdown now
```

It works immediately. Last change I made was to add a wake on lan service:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/wol.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Configure Wake On LAN

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/ethtool -s enp12s0 wol g

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable wol.service
sudo systemctl start wol.service
```

I have also tried to edit /etc/default/grub from:

```
RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

And make:

```
sudo update-grub
```

After a reboot, nothing changes. The problem still exists.

When I try:

```
shutdown -h now
```

The following error message comes:

> Failed to power off system via logind: There's already a shutdown or
> sleep operation in progress

Log:

```
usr1@ubuntu-nb:~$ journalctl -a -p err -b
-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-07-13 15:42:03 CEST, end at Wed 2020-07-29 21:07:46 CEST. --
Jul 29 20:52:01 ubuntu-nb kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0000 Jul 29 20:53:35 ubuntu-nb gdm-password][1695]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jul 29 20:59:06 ubuntu-nb gdm-password][3270]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jul 29 21:02:13 ubuntu-nb gdm-password][4508]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
```

Any ideas? This behavior exists after each start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo poweroff
```

This should work.

Comment: Over terminal I can shutdown the system. But this issue happens after each system start. So this is only a temporary solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a shutdown process in progress as the output for `shutdown -h now` says.

Try to cancel the shutdown operation by doing `shutdown -c`

Then try to power off the machine.

Comment: I already tried this, but it doesn't work. Also when I restart the system and click on loginmask shutdown over gui, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Wake On Lan is enabled in the bios/UEFI...
(if there are other WOL related settings in your bios/UEFI test those.)